# "Select all Documents from one content" hibernate relationship many to many

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

**I have tow models:**

```
 @Entity    
    public class Documento implements java.io.Serializable {

        @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "appc_contenido_documento", catalog = "appcope", 
        joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_documento", nullable = false, updatable = 
        false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_contenido", nullable = false, updatable = 
        false)})
    private Set<Contenido> contenidos = new HashSet<Contenido>(0);

}
```

**and**

```
@Entity   
public class Contenido implements java.io.Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
     private Integer id;

     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinTable(name = "appc_contenido_documento", catalog = "appcope", 
         joinColumns = {
     @JoinColumn(name = "id_contenido", nullable = false, updatable = 
         false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
     @JoinColumn(name = "id_documento", nullable = false, updatable = 
         false)})
     private Set<Documento> documentos = new HashSet<Documento>(0);

}
```

I don´t find an example this, only I find examples with relationship **one to many**

**How can I select all the documents of a content with CriteriaQuery?**

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good idea to reduce your many to many relationship to one to many. This usually can be done by introducing a bridging entity. It maybe worth adding such a table here.

Comment: Is there no way to do it without modifying the code of the current entities?

Comment: You should change the current code as it's not very flexible. I'm assuming you want to map content to documents. You should think about it in terms of 1 document can have many content or many types of content belong to a single document.